# Custom Toast for Android

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, position, monodevelop, toast

I am using MonoDevelop for Android and would please like some help with creating a custom toast.

Here is my code:

```
    static public void DisplayCustomToast (Context displayContext, string stringText, int offsetX, int offsetY)
    {
        Toast toast = new Toast(displayContext);
        toast.SetText(stringText);
        toast.SetGravity (GravityFlags.Top, offsetX, offsetY);
        //toast.Show;
    }
```

This code is not working. It Builds successfully, yet the application doesn't start properly.

If I uncomment the 'toast.show', get the following error:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

May I please have some help in getting this code working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `toast.Show` implies that `Show` is either a property or a field. That's why the call `toast.Show` is illegal.

However, I believe `Show` is a method. So you must invoke it this way:

`toast.Show();`